# Adding an Android library to a project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I am trying to add a slide menu to my android application.

- Imported the android library into workspace
- In my application project properties under android I clicked "Add" and added the library to my application
- Clicked "Apply" and then "Ok"

If I go to properties -> Android again the library I just added is not there anymore.
What could cause this?

After adding library:
[image]

After going to properties again:
[image]

**Edit:**

I ended up adding the project manually in project.properties

```
android.library.reference.2=../SlideMenu
```

And now it tells me what the problem is. Any idea how to resolve this?

[2013-10-06 19:57:15 - AtlasMobile] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2013-10-06 19:57:25 - AtlasMobile] Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2013-10-06 19:57:25 - AtlasMobile] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2013-10-06 19:57:25 - AtlasMobile] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2013-10-06 19:57:25 - AtlasMobile] Versions found are:

Comment: Screenshot or it didn't happen :)

Comment: @shoerat Added screen shots

Comment: Can you try to remove the space in Slide Menu library path?

Comment: @shoerat removed space from the main folder, removed space from the project name. Re-imported the project. Still same result

Comment: Open the library, turn off automatic builds, clean projects, and try again.

Comment: Is `project.properties` writable by Eclipse?

Comment: @323go turning off automatic build did not help

Comment: @shoerat How can i know whether it's writable by eclipse or not? thanks

Comment: @shoerat thanks your comment got me a little closer. I updated the question

Comment: Pretty much self explanatory, no? _All versions of the libraries must be the same_ --- seems like one of the libraries is using old version of `android-support-v4.jar`. I'd copy `android-support-v4.jar` from SDK folder and copy to library projects.

Comment: @shoerat Leave an answer so I can accept Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies... Found 3 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list, but **not all the versions are identical** (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time). All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.

Seems like one of the libraries is using old version of `android-support-v4.jar`. Please check if there are any updates available for library projects, maintainers of the libraries may already have updated `android-support-v4.jar`.

If the above does not help, I'd copy `android-support-v4.jar` that comes with the SDK and paste into library projects.

Answer (score 0):

check your java build path check all libraries that you have imported in project. finally click on ok.